Can house pets show signs of zoochosis?
Animals in captivity can show mental problems, it's been observed in zoos and aquariums. Very limited area can negatively impact animal leading them to such things like over-grooming pacing or even self-mutilation.
Could house pets that are kept indoors all the time, like for example cats, shows signs of zoochosis or other mental problems?
Source

Yes. Zoochosis doesn't seem to be an accepted term in the scientific community yet, however, this sort of thing is known as stereotypic behaviour, so unless you know that term, you would have trouble finding any scientific reports. As far as I can tell these behaviours are a often a result of boredom and stress.
It is very common in household pets, particularly those on the intelligent end of the scale, like parrots.
Many sources (e.g. AllAboutParrots.com) will tell you signs to watch out for in parrots that are bored - it often results in destructive behaviours, including self-mutilation (usually plucking feathers, but also gnawing on limbs). This has also been scientifically studied
Cats exhibit this sort of behaviour, particularly if weaned or taken away from their mothers early (<12 weeks). They can also exhibit obsessive-compulsive behaviours
Dogs also show stereotypic behaviours, particularly when not walked regularly.
Farm animals exhibit stereotypies, you can even see it in chickens and you can even breed to select against some of these behaviours.
I think it is safe to say that most animals that are kept confined and a non-stimulating environment will experience some form of stereotypical behaviour, whether we recognize it or not at this point in time. Certainly for those species we interact with a lot we can see it frequently.
